# долгая запись в файл

Tags: windows-10, файловая-система, ntfs

Что произойдет, если на диск постоянно записывать данные?
Меня интересует возможные ошибки или зависания.

Исходные данные:

1. жесткий диск (далее ЖД) формата NTFS с ОС windows 10.
2. ПО которая постоянно записывает телеметрию со скоростью 12 Мбайт/с.
3. Программа написана на QT и использует стандартную ф-цию записи в файл.

Что произойдет, если ЖД не дефармитирован, и запись файла дойдет до другого файла на ЖД? Как ведет себя ОС? Возможно ли другие ошибки? Как с ними бороться?

Comment: Ошибки. Системе NTFS уже более 10 лет. Думаю драйвер достаточно хорошо обкатали. Не помню когда ошибки появлялись под NTFS.

Comment: Если вы хотите что б ОС не занималась "поиском свободных кластеров" - создайте файл сразу нужного размера.

Comment: @nick_n_a хорошая идея

Comment: Для высоких скоростей лучше использовать File Mapping, которое работает быстрее чем WriteFile. Так же почитайте ММХ копирование памяти. Используйте выравнивание в памяти (как обычной так и дисковой) по границами 4К (для диска возможно даже 8К, а точнее по размеру кластера) для больших структур данных. File Maping без выравнивания в памяти - результатов не даст.